# How to combine two manual classifications

Tags: sentiment-analysis, labeling

We are manually classifying texts as positive (+1), neutral (0) or negative (-1). The purpose is to train a sentiment analysis classifier.

We are two people, and we have both classified the same subset (about 500 texts) with a kappa of around 0.8. When we both agree in the same it is clear that it is the "correct" label, but  in the case where we do not agree, how to choose the best label? is there any technique to combine two classification labels into a single one?

Comment: What is the purpose of the classification?  There are many techniques to combine the labels, of which one of the simplest would be to create a third label denoting disagreement.  Obviously there are many possible variations of that, which is why we need more information to determine what might be advisable.

Comment: The purpose is to train a sentiment analysis classifier, thus we need to decide which label associate to each text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "good" answer to this problem, but I have some suggestions:

1. selecting with your partner the "rigth" label by comparing both point of views (human approach).
2. If you disagree, duplicate the observations in the dataset with both labels. The idea is that sentiments are not absolute and the model could learn from uncertainty (my favorite solution).
3. fit your model with only observation for which you agreed. Then look at the model predictions on the other observations. It could help you to select a category.
4. for each uncertain observation, fit one model for both label and keep the label giving the model with the best prediction capacity. I do not like this approach because it could lead to some kind of overfitting.

Have fun !

Comment: I haven't thought of solution 2, and indeed seems the best, I will try this